# How can I get chain id of goerli test network?

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to connect metamask with goerli test network.
But I don't know what the chain id of goerli test network.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxl2L.png)
Please help me.

I've tried everything but I can't add network to the metamask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chaind id of goerli is `5`.  You'll have to choose a rpc node provider like [infura](https://docs.infura.io/infura/reference/network-endpoints) or [alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-add-alchemy-rpc-endpoints-to-metamask#step-4-fill-in-the-network-details).